SharePoint migration, users, MIM
Context

SharePoint On-Premise (SP1) environment, associated with different ADs (AD1, AD2, AD3). These Active Directories are federated by an ADFS.

Microsoft 365 tenant.

Some users in the AD1, 2 and 3 domains have an EntraID account, even if there is no account synchronization (AAD-Connect / CloudConnect type) between EntraID and AD1,2,3.

SharePoint On-Premise environment (SP2), associated with an AD4.

SP2 checks user authorizations by connecting to EntraID using the EntraCP component.

SP1 users will connect to SP2.

A MIM server is set up to link ADFS and EntraID accounts. Key: “mail” attribute.

We want to synchronize these users' profiles on SharePoint SP2 using the “Enable External Identity Manager” synchronization framework.


Requirement

Create/implement the appropriate SPMA MIM for the ADFS context. We can see users in SharePoint central admin but we cannot use them in people pickers... Does anybody get information about it?

I do not see any other information I could give... The context is complex, problem is Microsoft seems no more concerned by on premise and so there is not a lot of documentation ...
